# Data entered in a form doesn't get insert in the table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I cannot see the added data in the data table this is the code:

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t1 = textBox1.Text;

    SqlCeConnection conn =
       new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");

    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT TO table_name (Column1) VALUES (t1)";

    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

It doesn't insert into data table after clicking on the button, it gives me an error on

```
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it debugs it, but when I click on the button, it shows me an error saying

> *SqlCeException was unhandled. There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = TO ]*

Comment: Does the insert work when you run it in SSMS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t1", textBox1.Text);
cmdInsert.CommandText = "insert INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (@t1)";
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code:

- Syntax error in SQL statement - you should write `INSERT INTO` instead of `INSERT TO`.
- You cannot use `t1` directly in the SQL string. Although you could concatenate strings as suggested in other comments, it's better to use parametrized command instead.

Here is the corrected version:

```
SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (@t1)";
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t1", t1);
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

See [Why do we need SqlCeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() to Insert a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592609/why-do-we-need-sqlcecommand-parameters-addwithvalue-to-insert-a-value) for more details on command parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is wrong.

Instead of

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT TO table_name (Column1) VALUES (t1)";
```

There should be

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (t1)";
```

Comment: The variable `t1` still isn't reachable. It would need to be a parameterized query and a parameter would need added to the command like in the answer provided by @Andomar.

Answer (score 1):

```
string t1 = textBox1.Text;
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT into table_name (Column1) VALUES ('" + t1 + "')";
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: This is a teaching moment for someone new to queries.  We **should** not be telling the OP to not use a parameterized query.  See Andromar's answer below.

Comment: The approach is flawed, and it introduces a [Sql Injection Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I would still use:  `cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t1", textBox1.Text);  cmdInsert.CommandText = "insert INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (@t1)";`.  As Michael just mentioned, **NOT** using a parameterized query invites a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Not such a bad answer.  If your database has sysadmin password "welcome", there is absolutely no point in worrying about SQL injection.

Comment: @Andomar Thanks really very much. I need appreciation from guys like you.

Comment: @kashif - I upvoted your post once again. And am always happy to talk code with you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value of `t1`, probably with a parameter.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t1 = textBox1.Text;
    SqlCeConnection conn =
       new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (@t1)";
    var parameter = cmdInsert.CreateParameter();
    parameter.Value = t1;
    parameter.ParameterName = "@t1";

    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```